# Unexpected value 'template' in yaml template

Tags: templates, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, environment, azure-pipelines-yaml

Is there any way to declare environments in Yaml template?

I tried to fetch values of environemnt from pipeline to template file,but it showing error like "unexpected value 'template'".

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Hi Lalls, any update? Has my post helped?

Answer (score 1):

If you are going to pass the run your pipeline and parse the environment name into the template for the deployment targeting sepcific environments. I suppose you could test with yaml below. If I misunderstand you, you could share more details.

For the `template.yaml`

```
parameters:
- name: env
  type: string
  default: 'dev'

stages:
- stage: deployment_${{ parameters.env }}
  jobs:
  - deployment: envDeployment
    displayName: deploy to environment
    pool:
      vmImage: windows-latest
  # creates the environment if it doesn't exist
    environment: 'smarthotel_${{ parameters.env }}'
    strategy:
      runOnce:
        deploy:
          steps:
          - script: deploy to the ${{ parameters.env }} environgment
```

For the main pipeline `azure-pipeline.yaml`

```
trigger: none

pool: 
  vmImage: windows-latest

stages:
- template: template.yml
  parameters:
    env: dev
- template: template.yml
  parameters:
    env: qa
- template: template.yml
  parameters:
    env: prod
```